# uglify-js node module not installing with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, uglifyjs

Whenever I try to install uglify-js with npm on my Raspberry Pi, I get an error. I am trying to install jade, and uglify is a dependency. Express install fails as well.

To me, it looks like either npm or node.js is outdated.

npm version = 1.1.4, node.js version = 0.6.19, I am using the npmjs.eu registry mirror for npm.

To install nodejs and npm, I did `sudo apt-get install nodejs npm.` I have updated everything I could. What is the problem?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ npm update -g npm
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ npm install uglify-js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.eu/uglify-js
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.eu/uglify-js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.eu/uglify-to-browserify
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.eu/async
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.eu/source-map
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.eu/optimist
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.eu/uglify-to-browserify
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.eu/async
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.eu/optimist
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.eu/source-map
npm ERR! error installing uglify-js@2.4.12

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: source-map@'>=0.1.7- <0.2.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/pi/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.25+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "uglify-js"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: source-map@'>=0.1.7- <0.2.0-'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3"]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your installation of node. node v0.6.x is quite old and v0.10.26 is the current stable version (as of this writing).

If you're on Debian, v0.10.26 is available from the [wheezy-backports, jessie, and sid](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nodejs&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) repos.

If you're on Ubuntu, you can use [this](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) repo to easily stay up to date.

I'm not sure about packages for other platforms, but if nothing else there are always pre-compiled binary tarballs and source code (which is an easy `./configure && make && sudo make install`) available on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org).